# Use named range within index match

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a named range (DATA_DUMP_GROCERY) that I am trying to pull values from using index match. Here is my formula:

```
 =INDEX(DATA_DUMP_GROCERY,MATCH(Confectionery!$B$15,DATA_DUMP_GROCERY,0),4)
```

As you can see I am trying to specify which column to use with a number, as I usually do when using Index and Match together. This does not work however, I am getting the #N/A error.

How can I achieve pulling out values for a particular row within my array?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `!` after `DATA_DUMP_GROCERY` in the range portion for INDEX? The `!` shouldn't be there unless you are referencing a cell on another tab. It should just be the range name.

Comment: Woops silly mistakes there. Many thanks for the response. I've edited the question. Some improvement, the formula runs but is now giving an #N/A.

Comment: Have you tried to use the actual range values in place of the named range? I don't think `INDEX MATCH` formulas can use a table array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INDEX/MATCH` is perfectly capable of using Named Ranges that are a table of data. If a 2-D (table) of data is acceptable in the place you use it.

However, you use it in two different places and so need two different things.

In the actual `INDEX()` portion of the formula, you need first to give it a range to base everything upon. You do, `DATA_DUMP_GROCERY` being that range. Perfectly fine. `DATA_DUMP_GROCERY` is presumably a 2-D table of data, so this is exactly what the most common use of `INDEX()` needs and the function is happy.

However, you then give the same Named Range to `MATCH()` but it needs a single column to examine. (Actually, there are ways one can make that multiple columns, but not like you did.) Since you gave it a data table with more than one column, it fails. That failure causes the whole thing to fail.

You can use `INDEX()` inside `MATCH()` to extract a single column from the Named Range and present that to `MATCH()`, or you can simply type the single column address reference, or even create another Named Range holding that address.

My preference would be a very simple one:  the first thought, using `INDEX()` inside `MATCH()`:

```
=INDEX(DATA_DUMP_GROCERY,MATCH(Confectionery!$B$15,
       INDEX( DATA_DUMP_GROCERY,,1  ,  0),4)
```

Easy since the parameters for that `INDEX()` are likely simple ands straightforward, eh? No need for anything for ROW since you want all the rows, and whatever column number the lookup data are in (column 1 in the formula above).

Then it will all work very nicely.